# Yii2 submit ajax insert twice data to my table

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

on Yii2 Advanced My form insert twice in table, if I click twice my submit button my form insert data to my table twice it's like I clicked two time on my submit button; I'm using ajax for submit my form;  my form in view is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#upload-gallery").on('submit',(function(e) {
            $form = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    document.getElementById("upload-gallery").reset();
                    $.pjax.reload({container: '#some_pjax_id', async: false});
                },
                    error: function(){}             
           });
        }));    
    });
</script>

<div class="post-gallery-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'upload-gallery', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model_PstGlr, 'PGalleryFile[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model_PstGlr, 'post_text')->textarea(['rows' => 2]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model_PstGlr, 'permission_id')->dropdownList($model_Permission->PermissionOn()) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

and my controller is

```
public function actionView($chn)
{
    $model_Permission = new Permission;

    $model_PstGlr = new PostGallery;    $acc_PstGlr = new AxPostGallery;

    if ($model_PstGlr->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
    {
        $acc_PstGlr->CreateGallery($model_PstGlr, $chn);
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($chn),
        'model_Permission' => $model_Permission,
        'model_PstGlr' => $model_PstGlr,

    ]);
}
```

The upload gallery function is to upload images on my contents

--

```
public function CreateGallery ($MPGALLERY, $CHNID)
    {
        $PSTID = Yii::$app->params['PSTID'];
        $USRID = Yii::$app->user->id;

        $MPGALLERY->post_id = $PSTID;
        $MPGALLERY->user_id = $USRID;
        $MPGALLERY->channel_id = $CHNID;

        $ly_lgIMGFolder = 'upload/gal/'. $CHNID . '/' . $PSTID . '/' .date('YzHis');

        $GLRID = Yii::$app->params['GLRID'];

        $MPGALLERY->PGalleryFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($MPGALLERY, 'PGalleryFile');

        if( $MPGALLERY->save() )
        {
            mkdir($ly_lgIMGFolder, 0777, true);

            foreach ($MPGALLERY->PGalleryFile as $GImage)
            {
                $MGALLERY = new Gallery;

                $MGALLERY->post_id = $PSTID;

                $GImage->saveAs($ly_lgIMGFolder ."/". $GLRID . '.' . $GImage->extension);

                $MGALLERY->gallery_lgimage = $ly_lgIMGFolder ."/". $GLRID . '.' . $GImage->extension;

                $MGALLERY->save(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: add complete code, you havent added `CreateGallery` method from your model

Comment: I did add the CreateGallery function to my code

Comment: i dont find anything fishy here are you sure you are not binding the submit event twice, is there only one ajax request shown in the console tab?

Comment: and the record added twice, is for ? `Gallery` or `PGallery` ?

Comment: for both for PGallery and Gallery, it's record twice PGallery and Gallery

Comment: there got to be something else, there isn't any such thing as i said before, but you didn't answered **are you sure you are not binding the submit event twice, is there only one ajax request shown in the console tab**

Comment: yes, this is the only ajax submit on my web

Answer (score 0):

Appatently, there are a few changes that you may need to make in your code. 
For example, create the following function in your controller, and remove the code from your view.

```
public function actionSave(){
//This part is removed from the actionView, so that the request only saves and does nothing else; 
//You can return it back if you test and see that it works
$model_PstGlr = new PostGallery;    $acc_PstGlr = new AxPostGallery;
   if ($model_PstGlr->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
   {
    $acc_PstGlr->CreateGallery($model_PstGlr, $chn);
   }
}
```

Then on the view, modify your form initialization as follows
The reason for adding the forwad slash is to prevent apache from sending the request to a new URL that ends with the `'/'`;

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action'=> 'id' => 'upload-gallery', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
```

I hope this one now helps;

Comment: I tryed is not working; I click only one click but it's insert twice

Comment: @Bynd Try to remove  `$(document).ready(function (e) {`   and replace it with `jQuery(function ($) {` and let me know if it still submits twice.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you have are loading the main jquery file twice, or it is also loaded by another java-script file?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Okay, let me see if we can find an alternative. The scenario actually repeated itself even on my test server.

Comment: I have modified the solution that I had given earlier, I hope this will work. I have tested it on my site and it works fine. Hope it works for you.

Comment: But I need to use my form in actionView not actionSave

Comment: Yes, the form will still be on `actionView` the function for saving is the only thing separated. Your form will still be loaded, and it will save. Have you tried it?

Comment: but I need to use this variable $chn, is't from view actionView($chn) I use it for this function $acc_PstGlr->CreateGallery($model_PstGlr, $chn);

Comment: You can create a hidden field and pass the variable as one of the fields there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174075/discussion-between-paul-wakhungu-and-bynd).